# Rails: Store pervious URL even if page is redirected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my application controller I have something like this:

```
after_filter :store_location

def store_location
  # store last url as long as it isn't a /users path
  session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end
```

This works fine for storing the previous url, however on some pages I automagically redirect to the sign in page like so:

```
before_filter :require_login

def require_login
  unless current_user
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

On pages where the user is redirected (with the require_login filter) it does not store the previous url. It simply defaults them to the root_path.

How can I properly store the previous url for users who are redirected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`devise` provides this method called `stored_location_for` which will do the work for you

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The issue was that I using:

```
after_filter :store_location
```

but the storing of the url needed to happen right away (before the redirect). So the problem was solved by using:

```
before_filter :store_location
```

and making sure it falls before:

```
before_filter :require_login
```